# Prove that $\left|\pi f\left(0,0\right)-\int \int _{\left|x\right|< 1}fd\lambda _2\right|<\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Prove that $\left|\pi f\left(0,0\right)-\int \int _{\left|x\right|< 1}fd\lambda _2\right|<\frac{3}{2}$,  if $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, f\in C^2$ and for every $x\in \mathbb R^2$ and $ j,k \in \left\{1,2\right\}$ is $\left|\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial {x_j}\partial {x_k}}\left(x\right)\right|\le 1$.

Undoubtedly I must use $\left|\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial {x_j}\partial {x_k}}\left(x\right)\right|\le 1$ but I don't know how I can do it because I don't know if I can use Fubini's theorem and this is my only idea to use it.

Comment: It suffices to bound $|f(x_1, x_2) - f(0,0)|$. You can approximate $f(x_1, x_2)$ with the Taylor polynomial of order $2$. The condition on the second order partial derivatives will help. Do you have any information about the first order partial derivatives?

Comment: @angryavaian: I think the first derivative doesn't matter since the domain of integration is symmetric, so that any linear function integrates to zero.

Comment: @PhoemueX ok, using hints from you and @ agryavian I get: $|\pi f(0,0)-\int \int _{\left|x\right|< 1}fd\lambda _2|=|\pi f\left(0,0\right)-\frac14f_{x_1x_2}|$ but I don't know what I can do with $f(0,0)$

Comment: It seems you did not consider the Zero-Order term of the Taylor formula. By "linear", I really meant "linear", not "affine-linear". The constant term does not integrate to zero.

Comment: @PhoemueX Oh, I'm sorry, my mistake. However then the coefficient of the $f(0,0)$ is $\pi-1$ so it still doesn't get deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many mentioned, the answer is in the second order Taylor approximation of the function around $(0,0)$. Note that $\pi f(0,0) = \int\int_{|x| \leq 1} f(0,0)$, so, 
$$
\left|\pi f\left(0,0\right)-\int \int _{\left|x\right|< 1}fd\lambda _2\right| = \left| \int \int _{} \left(f(x)-f(0,0)\right) \right|
$$
Write $f(x_1,x_2) = $ Its second order Taylor expansion with error terms. Then integrate.

The reason the first order terms do not show up is because $ \int \int_{\left|x\right|< 1} x_1 = \int \int_{\left|x\right|< 1} x_2 = 0 $ due to the symmetry in domain and anti-symmetry of the integrands. (Reflection against the origin.) So, any integral of the form $ \int \int_{\left|x\right|< 1} a x_1 + b x_2 $ for constants a and b vanishes. Here a and b will be your first derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Thus, you are left with bounding terms such as $ \int \int_{\left|x\right|< 1} \partial_{xx} f $ and $ \int \int_{\left|x\right|< 1} \partial_{xy}f $ etc. for which the bound is given by the question.